# Initialize several variable from console input

Tags: python-3.x, console-application

as the title say, i need to affect values to several variable from one console input.
 I would like to store 3 number at once from an input line looking like this:
 -number1-space-number2-space-number3-
Right now i am doing it like this:

```
numbers = input("Enter three numbers separated by spaces: ")
nb1 = int(numbers.split()[0])
nb2 = int(numbers.split()[1])
nb3 = int(numbers.split()[2])
```

**But it wouldnt surprise me if you could do something like this:**

```
nb1, nb2, nb3 = input("Enter three numbers separeted by spaces: ",? ,?)
```

*Replace question mark by code actually working.* 
So if you know a better way of doing this, i would be thankfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg = "Enter three numbers separated by spaces: "
n1, n2, n3 = (int(n) for n in input(msg).split())
```